# How to tell ethminer the specific account/address where Ether should be put in?

Tags: mining, cpp-ethereum, ethminer, solo-mining

On the farming machine i have two accounts:

```
> geth account list
```

> 0x.......1
>
> 0x.......2

i've started ethminer with `ethminer -G` and the Ether lands in the first account. But i want it being farmed into the second account, as the second one is an imported wallet.

'ethminer --help' does not offer any option for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be

```
geth -G --etherbase value (0 or 1)
```

depending on how many accounts you have. You having 2 accounts, you choose  which one you want.

Default value is 0 so I'm guessing you want the second account

```
geth -G --etherbase value 1
```

is what I think you would type.